# How to copy rows from one table to another, including a new column

Tags: jquery, html-table

I set up this function in Jquery, to copy the data from one table to another, but I was unable to include a new column, where there will be a button to be able to delete the row,

I need the copy_Table () function, when copying the data from table1 and pasting it into table2 in addition to the data in the table, to include a new column with a delete button

```js
function copy_Table() {
       $('#t2').append($('#t1').html());

    }


    function filterTable1() {
  const query = q => document.querySelectorAll(q);
  const filters = [...query('th input.input1')].map(e => new RegExp(e.value, 'i'));

  query('tbody.Enc_Despesas1 tr').forEach(row => row.style.display = 
    filters.every((f, i) => f.test(row.cells[i].textContent)) ? '' : 'none');
}

function onDelete(td) {

row = td.parentElement.parentElement;
document.getElementById("table2").deleteRow(row.rowIndex);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row">
  <table id="table1" border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><input onkeyup="filterTable1()" class="input1" name="form_txt"></th>
        <th><input onkeyup="filterTable1()" class="input1" name="form_txt"></th>
        <th><input onkeyup="filterTable1()" class="input1" name="form_txt"></th>   
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Food</th>
         <th>Cost</th>
         <th>Quantity</th>
         
      </tr>
    <tbody id="t1" class="Enc_Despesas1">
      <tr>
        <td>Apple</td>
        <td>$0.50</td>
        <td>18</td>
        
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bread</td>
        <td>$1.99</td>
        <td>7</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <table id="table2" border="1" style="margin-left: 2%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Food</th>
        <th>Cost</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="t2">
      <tr>
        <td>Broccoli</td>
        <td>$3.75</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <th><input type="button" value="Del"  onClick="onDelete(this)"></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Oranges</td>
        <td>$6.50</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <th><input type="button" value="Del"  onClick="onDelete(this)"></th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div style="align-self: center">
     <button onclick="copy_Table()" style="margin-left: 2%">Transfer Rows</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the replace function to find the closing tag of each row  and insert your  containing the delete button code

```js
function copy_Table() {
let tableRows = $('#t1').html()
tableRows = tableRows.replaceAll(
  '</tr>',
  '<th><input type="button" value="Del" onClick="onDelete(this)" /></th></tr>'
)
       $('#t2').append(tableRows);

    }


    function filterTable1() {
  const query = q => document.querySelectorAll(q);
  const filters = [...query('th input.input1')].map(e => new RegExp(e.value, 'i'));

  query('tbody.Enc_Despesas1 tr').forEach(row => row.style.display = 
    filters.every((f, i) => f.test(row.cells[i].textContent)) ? '' : 'none');
}

function onDelete(td) {

row = td.parentElement.parentElement;
document.getElementById("table2").deleteRow(row.rowIndex);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row">
  <table id="table1" border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><input onkeyup="filterTable1()" class="input1" name="form_txt"></th>
        <th><input onkeyup="filterTable1()" class="input1" name="form_txt"></th>
        <th><input onkeyup="filterTable1()" class="input1" name="form_txt"></th>   
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Food</th>
         <th>Cost</th>
         <th>Quantity</th>
         
      </tr>
    <tbody id="t1" class="Enc_Despesas1">
      <tr>
        <td>Apple</td>
        <td>$0.50</td>
        <td>18</td>
        
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bread</td>
        <td>$1.99</td>
        <td>7</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <table id="table2" border="1" style="margin-left: 2%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Food</th>
        <th>Cost</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="t2">
      <tr>
        <td>Broccoli</td>
        <td>$3.75</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <th><input type="button" value="Del"  onClick="onDelete(this)"></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Oranges</td>
        <td>$6.50</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <th><input type="button" value="Del"  onClick="onDelete(this)"></th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div style="align-self: center">
     <button onclick="copy_Table()" style="margin-left: 2%">Transfer Rows</button>
  </div>
</div>
```